# Listen to changes in array

Tags: java, arrays, javafx, observable

I need some help if you can spare a few minutes.
I am in a bit of a pickle as I try to make this work.

I have a javaFX class like this

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class FoorballTeam extends Application {
int i1=0;  
int i3=0;
String[] PlayerNames = new String[12];
int[] goals = new int[12];

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

    player[] playerData = new player[12];

    Button btn = new Button();
    btn.setText("add Player");

    GridPane root = new GridPane();
    root.add(btn,0,0);

    int i2;
    for (i2=0;i2<=11;i2++)
    {playerData[i2]=new player();}        

    btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {

           playerData[i3].player(root, i3);
           i3++; 

        }
    });

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

    primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}

public String[] getPlayerNames() {
    return PlayerNames;
}

public void setPlayerNames(String[] PlayerNames) {
    this.PlayerNames = PlayerNames;
}

public int[] getGoals() {
    return goals;
}

public void setGoals(int[] goals) {
    this.goals = goals;
}

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

}
```

and a second class named player like this

```
import javafx.event.EventType;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;

public class player {

String NameOfPlayer = new String();    
int goalsOfPlayer;

public void player (GridPane root,int numberOfPlayer) 
{

TextField name = new TextField();
TextField goals = new TextField();

GridPane grid = new GridPane();
grid.add(name,0,0);
grid.add(goals,1,0);
root.add(grid,0,numberOfPlayer+1);

System.out.println("player " + numberOfPlayer + " added");

name.textProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
NameOfPlayer=newValue;

}); 

goals.textProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
goalsOfPlayer=Integer.parseInt(newValue);
});    


}
}
```

I want every time that I make a change to a players name or goals to pass this change on the two arrays PlayerNames[] and goals[] of the main class.
for example if player1 changes goals from 1 to 2 I want the goals[1]=2.
Also is it possible to put a listener to this two arrays so when a player changes name or goals to trigger the listener.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: To make your code easy to read, please indent it and follow [Java Naming Conventions](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-naming-conventions/).

Comment: I think it, rather than keeping the two arrays updated you could have a simple  functions that retrieve all updated values when needed  like `int[] getGoals()`

Comment: I found the solution to my first problem, but i believe there is no way to add a change listener to a variable.

Comment: `goals.textProperty().addListener...` isn't that adding listener to a variable ?

Comment: Thank you my friend for your answer,i want in class FoorballTeam the variable int[] goals = new int[12] to have a listener, is it possible;

Comment: Yes it is. Please post [mcve]. Mcve needs to show the problem you are trying to solve. **Not** your application.

Answer (score 0):

One simple solution is to warp the `int[]` array with an observable list, and listen to changes in this list :

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ListChangeListener;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ListenToArrayCahnges extends Application {

    private final int SIZE = 12;
    private final Integer[] goals = new Integer[SIZE];
    private final Random rand = new Random();
    private int counter = 0;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        Arrays.fill(goals, 0); //initial values
        //Warp array with an observable list. list back by array so it is of fixed length
        ObservableList<Integer> goalsList = FXCollections.observableArrayList(Arrays.asList(goals));
        //add listener to list
        goalsList.addListener((ListChangeListener<Integer>) c ->{
            //respond to list changes
            System.out.println("Goals changed to : "+ goalsList);
        });
        //button to change the list
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.setText("Add goal");    
        btn.setOnAction(event -> {
            goalsList.set(counter,  rand.nextInt(100));
            counter = ++counter % SIZE ; //increment counter 0,1,2....11 and back to 0
        });

        GridPane root = new GridPane();
        root.add(btn,0,0);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 150, 50);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Note that the posted [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) represents the **problem** that needs to be solved (or in this case a solution to it), and **not** the specific application or use case.